# Grouping strings by paragraph

Tags: python, list, iterator

I want to group a list of strings by "paragraph"; paragraphs being delimited by a single empty string.

The following code does what I want, but I am looking for a more elegant syntax (e.g. using `itertools`).

```
txt = ['First paragraph', ' continues',
       '',
       'Second ', 'paragraph']

para = [[]]
for ln in txt:
    if not ln:
        para.append([])
    else:
        para[-1].append(ln)
```

I am in fact looking for a sort of `group-while` function.

Comment: nothing wrong with what you are using

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: apart from requiring that all paragraphs fit in memory in one go. :-) If the lines came from a file or network socket, rather than a list, you may want to process the data in chunks, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, we would be talking a lot of paragraphs before that would be a problem

Comment: if you want more elegant syntax `para[-1].append(ln) if ln else para.append([])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

paragraphs = (list(g) for empty, g in groupby(txt, lambda l: not len(l)) if not empty)
```

This creates a generator that lists paragraphs, by grouping on line length:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> txt = ['First paragraph', ' continues',
...        '',
...        'Second ', 'paragraph']
>>> paragraphs = (list(g) for empty, g in groupby(txt, lambda l: not len(l)) if not empty)
>>> for para in paragraphs:
...     print para
... 
['First paragraph', ' continues']
['Second ', 'paragraph']
```